# Atualizar imagem com temporizador usando AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Eu tenho esta função:

```
 if ($files_count == 0) {
    ?>
    <img src="img/upload.gif">
    <?php
 }
```

E precisava que isto se atualizasse de 5 em 5 segundos sem dar ***refresh*** na página.
Já testei varias funções AJAX e não consigo. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Hmmm... falta aqui muita informação para ser possível responder a esta pergunta... O que é o `$files_count`?, pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer?

Comment: Olá, ja consegui resolver o problema. files_count é uma variavel com informaçao de uma tabela mysql. vou postar a solução

Answer (score 1):

Soluçao!

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
```

SCRIPT:

```
setInterval(function () {
    check_files();
}, 5000);

function check_files() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/php/file.php',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: {},
        success: function (resp) {
            if (resp == 0) {
                $('.container').html('<img src="img/upload.gif" />');
            } else {
                /// mais alguma coisa
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Pode explicar como este código resolveu o seu problema? Assim fica útil para outros que possam ter o mesmo problema no futuro

Comment: E já agora, acho que enviar pedidos AJAX com temporizador pode dar problemas. O melhor era fazer novo pedido com setTimeout disparado de dentro do `success` ou pelo menos haver uma flag aí que o `setibterval` vefirica.